# params is undefined in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-stack

My code was working fine until i install "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.8". Earlier I was using "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.3" packages. 
App.js :

```
 <Stack.Screen name="HomeRT" component={Home} />
 <Stack.Screen name="BlogDetailsRT", component={BlogDetails}/>
```

My package.json contains :

```
 "@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.3",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^5.2.8",
 "react-navigation": "^4.2.2",
"react-navigation-stack": "^2.2.3"
```

Home.js:

```
 <Text style={styles.TextStyle} onPress={() => this.props.navigation.navigate('BlogDetailsRT', { id:blog_id })}>{blogname}</Text>
```

BlogDetails.js:

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        blog_id: this.props.navigation.state.params.id
    };
```

Here it shows an error message "TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined".

Comment: My best guesses will be: 1) Get rid of either @react-navigation/stack or react-navigation-stack dependency. 2) there is a coma in the BlogDetailsRT screen declaration.
Maybe both of these options cause the trouble.

Comment: try to access the props directly by removing `this`. Like this `props.navigation.state.params.id`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have uninstalled react-navigation-stack & react-navigation. I have remove coma as well, still getting can't read property params of undefined

Comment: @AnurodhSingh : Getting 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined'.

Comment: You should use react-navigation then.

Comment: It navigates to other pages if there is no params. For ex: this.props.navigation.navigate('otherRT'), It navigates to otherRT page.

Answer (score -1):

Try below code

```js
state = {
   search: this.props.navigation.getParam("searchText", "")
};
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this code.. but getting 'TypeError: _this.props.navigation.getParam is not a function'..

Comment: Give initial value in `<Stack.screen` for id param.